# Select data based on priority using 2 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, max

I'm a beginner in SQL. I need to select distinct data (Subject, UserNo) ordering by columns Subject, UserNo according to the priority conditions below.

Conditions:

1. Select (Subject, UserNo) that has highest rates from Table A
2. If two or more subjects have the same rating from Table A, then Select (Subject, UserNo) highest rates from Table B having same subjects.

If the data satisfies condition 1 (like user_1/user_2/user_4) then just get data from Table A.

But, if the rates are same ordering by Subject and UserNo (like user_3 / user_5), then join with table B that has same A.Subject and A.UserNo and get data (Subject, UserNo) from Table B

[Table A]

| Subject | UserNo | highest_Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | user_1 | 10 |
| A | user_2 | 8 |
| A | user_3 | 5 |
| B | user_3 | 5 |
| B | user_4 | 10 |
| C | user_5 | 20 |
| D | user_5 | 20 |

[Table B]

| Subject | UserNo | highest_Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | user_1 | 10 |
| A | user_2 | 8 |
| A | user_3 | 100 |
| B | user_3 | 5 |
| B | user_4 | 10 |
| C | user_5 | 20 |
| D | user_5 | 200 |

Expected result set:

| Subject | UserNo |
| --- | --- |
| A | user_1 |
| A | user_2 |
| A | user_3 |
| B | user_4 |
| D | user_5 |

Can you tell me how to make query I want in SQL Server?

```
SELECT
    A.Subject, A.UserNo, A.highest_Rate
FROM
    Table A
INNER JOIN
    Table B ON A.UserNo = B.UserNo 
            AND A.Subject = B.Subject
```

Since I can't access database now, I can't tell the detail I tried to queried.

Comment: Why is subject C missing? i don't really understand your logic, but a plus for test data!

Comment: I don't understand it, too. User 2 is part of the result although it has not the highest rate for any subject. Why that?

Comment: maybe it's "for every user, fetch subject matching the highest rate" either from table a or b as tiebreaker?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```sql
select UserNo, Subject
from (
    select t.UserNo, t.Subject
    , row_number() over(partition by t.userno order by t.highest_rate desc, t2.highest_rate desc) as sort
    from (
        VALUES  (N'A', N'user_1', 10)
        ,   (N'A', N'user_2', 8)
        ,   (N'A', N'user_3', 5)
        ,   (N'B', N'user_3', 5)
        ,   (N'B', N'user_4', 10)
        ,   (N'C', N'user_5', 20)
        ,   (N'D', N'user_5', 20)
    ) t (Subject,UserNo,highest_Rate)
    left join (
        VALUES  (N'A', N'user_1', 10)
        ,   (N'A', N'user_2', 8)
        ,   (N'A', N'user_3', 100)
        ,   (N'B', N'user_3', 5)
        ,   (N'B', N'user_4', 10)
        ,   (N'C', N'user_5', 20)
        ,   (N'D', N'user_5', 200)
    ) t2 (Subject,UserNo,highest_Rate)
        ON  t2.userNo  = t.UserNo
        AND t2.Subject = t.Subject
    ) x
where x.sort = 1
```

For every user, row_number will return order by first the main table's highest_rate and as tiebreaker the second table's highest rated ordered by DESC.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you tell me how to make query I want in SQL Server?

I hope I understood your requirements correctly, then you can try to use this SQL query:

```
SELECT Subject, UserNo
FROM (
  SELECT A.Subject, A.UserNo, MAX(A.highest_Rate) AS highest_Rate
  FROM tableA A
  GROUP BY Subject, UserNo
  UNION ALL
  SELECT B.Subject, B.UserNo, MAX(B.highest_Rate) AS highest_Rate
  FROM tableB B
  GROUP BY Subject, UserNo
) AS T
ORDER BY Subject, UserNo;
```